How can I understand what was the last time that Repository is updated using VDFS on the VisualSVN slave server?
I did setup two servers which running VisualSVN Server. One is the master and the other is the slave.
I did enabled VisualSVN Distributed File System on server and my repositories in order to have a copy of master repositories on the slave server.
But the questions is how can I check the repository on the slave server is updated and in sync with master server?
Are there any logs or anything like last updated time in properties of repositories to find that?

You typically don't ever need to trigger or force the VDFS replication to occur as it works automatically. But there are certain ways to ensure that the slave repository is up to date with its master partner:

You can run the Sync-SvnRepository PowerShell cmdlet to find out if the replication is running and check the replication's progress. If the output is empty, then the slave repository is up to date. You need to run this cmdlet on the slave server and provide the name of the slave repository. For example, run Sync-SvnRepository SLAVEREPO (replace SLAVEREPO with the actual name of the name of a slave repository).

The Sync-SvnRepository PowerShell cmdlet can also be used for ensuring that the slave repository is up to date. E.g., you can run the cmdlet in a script and when the command finishes, the slave repository can be considered to be up to date with its master repository.
Please see the article KB165: Using VisualSVN Server PowerShell module for instructions on using the PowerShell module and cmdlets included with VisualSVN Server.


And besides that you can check if the replication is up and running in the VisualSVN Server Replication Windows event log. The log does not show the progress of the replication, but it has events related to the replication in general (starting the VDFS service, stopping, replication failures due to network issues, replication recovering from those failures, etc.).
